# vue.js transition creates vertical scrollbar for just a second

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `Vue.js` and `transitions`.

This is my component.

```
 <main id="main-content" class="t-center" role="main">
            <transition :name="!phone ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'" mode="out-in">
                <keep-alive>
                    <component :is="stepComponent"  />
                </keep-alive>
            </transition>
        </main>
```

This is my `.scss`

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .3s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide-left-enter-active,
.slide-right-enter-active,
.slide-up-enter-active,
.slide-left-leave-active,
.slide-right-leave-active,
.slide-up-leave-active  {
    transition: transform .2s, opacity .2s;
}

.slide-left-enter,
.slide-right-enter,
.slide-up-enter,
.slide-left-leave-to,
.slide-right-leave-to,
.slide-up-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide-left-enter {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
}

.slide-left-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.slide-right-enter {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.slide-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
}

.slide-up-enter {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}

.slide-up-leave-to {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

Now, what happens is when the `stepComponent` changes, another component comes into place and the old one fades away from right to left and new component comes from right to left. but the issue is that for just a second or milliseconds, a vertical scrollbar appears and when the new component comes at final the place, that vertical scrollbar is removed.

the vertical scrollbar only appears if i test it on chrome (responsive mode).  If I test it on the same screen size as responsive, but not activate a responsive mode, then no vertical scrollbar appears and it's all good.

Why does vertical scrollbar appear? `overflow:hidden` didn't help.

Comment: trying to figure this out myself, it seems that the parent component div will need overflow:hidden for the transition period only.  did you figure this out?  does the transition come in from the right or left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, this might be a bit overkill, but when there is vue, there is a way. You can actually use the `life cycle event hooks` and `watchers` to flip the `overflow-y` property as @revliscano mentioned.

First, start watching the route changes. This is where we will get rid of the overflow-y. Every time, we change a route, overflow-y will be hidden.

```
 watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
        document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.overflowY = "hidden";
        console.log("hidden now");
 }
```

then, when the DOM is updated, we will put it back after a few miliseconds.

```
updated: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.overflowY = "auto";
        console.log("set to visible");
    }, 300);
},
```

`scrollContainer` is the inner div I use, but you should be able to change it to whichever the element you like.

You can keep this logic in your `App.vue`. So, your route-views will be left neat and tidy.